# Data not properly stored in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, postman

- I'm trying to get another service and that works pretty much fine,
  but the problem is, how to properly implement the logic to generate
  the cart items correctly and I want to increase quantity of cart by
  one on every function call, but as it seems it doesn't work on that
  way.
- In `Postman` I'm always getting the ID of selected data, that's the thing I want.
- So how to generate  `totalQty` variable to increasingly
  grow by 1 every time the function is called?

Here is retrieving information through another service and trying to fit it into an existing function `AddProduct()`.

```
app.get('/add-to-cart/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let cart = new Cart(req.body.cart ? req.body.cart : {});

    const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:4200/products');
    const singleProduct = await data.find((product) => product._id === id)
    
    cart.addProduct(singleProduct, singleProduct._id);
    
    req.body.cart = cart;

    res.redirect('/');
    console.log(req.body.cart);
  } 
  
  catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  
});
```

And here is the adding cart logic:

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.productItems = oldCart.productItems || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || oldCart.totalQty==0.00;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || oldCart.totalPrice==0.00;
   
    this.addProduct = function(item, id) {
        let storedItem = this.productItems;
        storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
        
        if (!storedItem){
            storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
            console.log("stored is empty")
        }
        else{
        
        console.log("Stored item full!")
        storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: storedItem.qty, price: storedItem.price}

        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        
        this.totalQty ++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.price;
        
    }
    }

    this.generateArray = function () {
        let arr = [];
        for (let id in this.productItems) {
            arr.push(this.productItems);
        }
        return arr;
    }};
```

This is what do I get with `console.log`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you have total quantity of 2 every time you test could be because you called add product once and then on your next line, you called cart.addProduct in console log again. You should store the results and then console log to prevent the double adding

```
cart.addProduct(singleProduct, singleProduct._id);
console.log(cart.addProduct(singleProduct, singleProduct._id)); // Remove this line
```

Change to this

```
const response =  cart.addProduct(singleProduct, singleProduct._id);
console.log('Cart response: ', response);
```

<strike>**Update 1 from the comment question:**
The reason why you keep getting total quantity 1 over and over again, I would think it is because you did not update your oldCart's qty. So you should return the storedItem after your addProduct and update oldCart.</strike>
.

**Update 2**
Ignore update 1, I saw the issue. The reason why totalQty 1 over and over again is because you create new cart on API call.

**Update 3 Updated your addProduct code:**
I noticed some errors in the code
e.g. 
`storedItem = this.productItems = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};`

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.productItems = oldCart.productItems || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || oldCart.totalQty==0.00;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || oldCart.totalPrice==0.00;
   
    this.addProduct = function(item, id) {
        let storedItem =  {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
        // Update here        
        if (this.productItems){
 
          console.log("Stored item full!")
          storedItem = {item: item, qty: storedItem.qty, price: storedItem.price}
        }
        console.log("totalQty: ",this.totalQty);

        console.log("Quantity 1: ",storedItem.qty);
        storedItem.qty++;
        console.log("Quantity 2: ",storedItem.qty);
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        
        this.totalQty ++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.price;
        
    }
    }

    this.generateArray = function () {
        let arr = [];
        for (let id in this.productItems) {
            arr.push(this.productItems);
        }
        return arr;
    }};
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even see that... So why am I getting total quantity 1 over and over, whenever I make an API call the total quantity is still 1. Can you update this in an answer?

Comment: The thing is I want my total quantity to be increased by 1 when the function is called, and for example on the 3rd call it should be `totalQty: 3`

Comment: Any idea how to solve this in the most efficient way? And again to increasingly raise quantity by one and other things like price. So not to overwrite data, just make data grow and grow depending on api calls.

Comment: I've updated your add product code, do see if this works

Comment: It still doesn't work in a proper way, I updated my question with `console.log` of your answer.

Comment: I added the data of your answer and `console.log` it, so I put a screenshot on my question.

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed 1 issue, correct me if i am wrong but is app.get a get request?...req.body.cart will always be empty if is a GET request... You need a POST request to send body...

Comment: But when I try to `console.log` cart which is equal to req.body.cart I still get the information, that means the request body is full somehow

Comment: I tried to put it ass app.post and it's still pretty much the same issue.